# Inline JS from file to HTML serverside

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat8

To speed up my web application, I want to embed my Javascript (located in a .min.js file) directly into my HTML body to remove the request for the file with script src="" tag.

Is there a standard way in Spring to read a JS/CSS/any-other-file and print it in HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I think that there isn't a standard way to minify and embed  JS and CSS, but there are a large number of tools you can use.

Be aware that if the script is very large (and your HTML code isn't static), only will load faster the first time you call the page, but for every subsequent request it will be faster to load the js and css files from cache.

Comment: Indeed, loading scripts separately is something that is done quite often and browsers have been optimized to handle such cases by caching the requests. Making the scripts inline would probably lead to less performant scenarios anyways.

Comment: So the answer is simply no. No standard ways in Spring?